# What is the reason for a = {b:4}[r,s,e]= ['Ronaldo', 'Messi', 'Aguero'] will give ['Ronaldo', 'Messi', 'Aguero'] as output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Let suppose we he a code block below -

```
function football(){
let options = {}
  let [r, s, e] = ['Ronaldo', 'Messi', 'Aguero']
  if(true){
    options = {league: 'Premier League'}
    [r, s, e] = ['Grealish', 'De Bruyne', 'Ramos']
    console.log(options, r, s, e)
  }
}
football()
```

Output of this code is - `['Grealish', 'De Bruyne', 'Ramos'] Ronaldo Messi Aguero`

Please suggest the reason why object assignment didn't work here without `; semicolon` in the `options` variable.

If we put a `semicolon ;` after like this- `options = {league: 'Premier League'};` then this would give the expected output - `{league: 'Premier League'} Grealish De Bruyne Ramos`.

Please anyone can explain the reason?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without the semicolon these two lines

```
options = {league: 'Premier League'}
[r, s, e] = ['Grealish', 'De Bruyne', 'Ramos']
```

are interpreted as a *single* expression:

```
options = {league: 'Premier League'}[r, s, e] = ['Grealish', 'De Bruyne', 'Ramos']
```

The `{league: 'Premier League'}[r, s, e]` part, while interesting, is irrelevant because the "return value" of an assignment expression is always the value that was assigned:

```js
let a = [];
let b = a[0] = 'first';
console.log(a, b);
// b = 'first' because the result of a[0] = 'first' is 'first'
```

Hence your code is equivalent to

```
options = ['Grealish', 'De Bruyne', 'Ramos']
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that `{ ... } [r, s, e]` is interpreted as: `{ ... }[e]` which will end up being an attempt to lookup the key `e` from the object `{ ... }` `e` being `"Ramos"` and the object being `{league: 'Premier League'}` resulting in `undefined`, so the expression ends up being `options = undefined = `[...]`.

Comment: @andlrc: No, the assignment (`{...}[...] = ...`) takes precedence so the property `"Ramos"` will actually be created.