# Why semicolons influence the behaviour of my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, semicolon-inference

I'm writing a quick sort function in Javascript to sort an array of objects like this (sort by the `Num` property):

```js
let Pairs = [
   { ID: 'C', Num: 21 },
   { ID: 'B', Num: 45 },
   { ID: 'F', Num: 0 },
   { ID: 'E', Num: 1 },
   { ID: 'D', Num: 9 },
   { ID: 'A', Num: 100 }
];
```

But I found out that adding semicolons in my function `partition()` solved the bug in my prorgam, without the semicolons behind the `swapPair()` function, my program gave out the same array as input.
Here is my code:

```js
const swapPair = (a, b) => {
   let t = a;
   a = b;
   b = t;
   return [a, b]
}
function partition(a, left, right, pivotIndex) {
   pivotValue = a[pivotIndex].Num;
   // Move Pivot to the End
   [a[pivotIndex].ID, a[right].ID] = swapPair(a[pivotIndex].ID, a[right].ID);// This Semicolon
   [a[pivotIndex].Num, a[right].Num] = swapPair(a[pivotIndex].Num, a[right].Num);// This Semicolon
   storeIndex = left;
   for (let i = left; i <= right - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i].Num <= pivotValue) {
         [a[storeIndex].ID, a[i].ID] = swapPair(a[storeIndex].ID, a[i].ID);// This Semicolon
         [a[storeIndex].Num, a[i].Num] = swapPair(a[storeIndex].Num, a[i].Num);// This Semicolon
         storeIndex = storeIndex + 1
      }
   }
   // Move Pivot to the right place
   [a[storeIndex].ID, a[right].ID] = swapPair(a[storeIndex].ID, a[right].ID);// This Semicolon
   [a[storeIndex].Num, a[right].Num] = swapPair(a[storeIndex].Num, a[right].Num);// This Semicolon
   return storeIndex
}
```

I guess the problem is the way I use destructing assignment? But I couldn't figure out the cause, Please help me out:).

---

**UPDATE:**

The problem is in deed destructing assignment, My function returns an array so this problem is pretty hard to notice:

```js
function foo(){
  ...
  return [a,b,c]
}

[A,B,C]=foo()
[D,E,F]=foo()
```

but without the semicolon, the code will be interperted as:

```
[A,B,C]=[x,y,z]
[D,E,F]=[m,n,p]
=>
[A,B,C]=[x,y,z][D,E,F]=[m,n,p]
=>
[A,B,C]=[x,y,z][F]=[m,n,p]
=>
[A,B,C]=[m,n,p]
```

Thank you Felix Kling.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68934612/218196 which I just answered a couple of days ago (but is a bit more specific than the duplicate).

Comment: You can write javascript without semicolon, you only need to insert them if you start a line with a parenthesis `(` or a bracket `[`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421633/9942418